# Database or XML

Tags: android, xml, database, performance

I'm programming a Chat App. Next step is to list all users in a listview (with image and co).

All around the listview ist done, but now i'm choose between reading contacts trough a xml file or reading trough a database (sqllite?). And later the same with the messages.

What should I use? Which of the two is faster (performance)?

Greez
Dancger

Comment: Database. It's builtin functionality. File operations are more complex.

Comment: For large sets  of data use data base. Also if your storing it xml file and parsing it later performance depends on on the parser also. SAX is better than DOm parser for large chunks on data in xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the data in a file could cause concurrency issues. Without using a database, you'll also have a lot of trouble filtering out data. Constantly accessing files will be memory heavy as well. A database is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, properly written database is faster and android contains a whole lots of things to use cursors and such.

JSON is nice because it is simple to use. a Contact list shouldn't be too big, so that would work.

As for XML, i really don't see why you would like to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Ya Can Use a MySQL database instead of the SqLite database or an XML file because contacts and messages can take a large space and you need to keep them stored (have a history) , so you need to have a database on a remote server and use JSON and a web service (php) to communicate and you will have a secured data and larger space to store .

Answer (score 0):

A local Sqlite database would be faster. For the contacts, it just depends on where you wanna save your contacts (online/local). I would choose the online option because, well that just makes more sense.